# Como configurar o Auth.Basic do Laravel para aceitar outro campo de autenticação?

Tags: laravel, autenticação

Estou utilizando o Laravel 5 e quero usar o middleware `auth.basic`. Porém no meu banco de dados, a tabela usada para autenticação (`usuarios`), não tem o campo `email`, e sim `username` - o padrão esperado pelo Laravel 5 é `email`.

Consegui configurar tranquilamente o `AuthController` para autenticar usando um campo customizado. Porém essas configurações não são as mesmas para o `auth.basic`, pois o seguinte erro está sendo gerado quando tento fazer esse tipo de autenticação:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'

Já pesquisei no Stackoverflow em Inglês, na documentação e olhei no código-fonte, e até agora não achei uma solução.

Alguém sabe uma maneira simples de configurar o `middleware` do `auth.basic` para poder fazer a autenticação `Basic`?

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362295/laravel-5-how-to-use-basic-auth-with-username-in-place-of-email

Comment: @Miguel isso mesmo :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dito no comentário pelo usuário @Miguel, para resolver o problema é necessário criar um novo `Middleware`, contendo a validação necessária para efetuar o login via `Auth Basic`.

1) Primeiro é necessário criar o `Middleware` novo. Rode o seguinte comando:

```
php artisan make:middleware AuthBasic
```

2) Em seguida, adicione a seguinte validação no `Middleware` criado:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AuthBasic
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return auth()->basic('username') ?: $next($request);
    }
}
```

Observe que no método `basic`, eu passei a `string` `"username"`. Isso é porque, por padrão, no método `SessionGuard::basic()`, temos o valor `"email"` definido por padrão.

Veja o código-fonte do método `basic` no arquivo `SessionGuard.php`:

```
public function basic($field = 'email', $extraConditions = [])
{
    if ($this->check()) {
        return;
    }

    // If a username is set on the HTTP basic request, we will return out without
    // interrupting the request lifecycle. Otherwise, we'll need to generate a
    // request indicating that the given credentials were invalid for login.
    if ($this->attemptBasic($this->getRequest(), $field, $extraConditions)) {
        return;
    }

    return $this->getBasicResponse();
}
```

3) Configure o seu novo `Middleware`, adicionando ele no `Http/Kernel.php`. Você deve substituir o indice `auth.basic` e adicionar o seu Middleware de Auth Basic - que está na propriedade `$routeMiddleware`.

Assim:

```
//'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
'auth.basic'  => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthBasic::class,
```